# Why does "virer" mean to UNemploy someone?

Tags: étymologie

English's "veer" descended from French's virer. How is virer (or veering) related to unemployment?

Based on English, I am surmising that  you are "veered off" employment? English's "veer" doesn't mean [UNemploy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unemploy). But "veer" can be used to describe your employment! I link to these websites just as examples — I am not affiliated or promoting them.

- [M.B.A.s Veer Off Path to Big Finance Jobs](https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB122697125541435813)
- [What to Do if Your Career Veers Off Course](https://lumawealth.com/blogs/news/what-to-do-if-your-career-veers-off-course).
- [5 Things You'll Learn when you veer off a traditional career path.](https://www.fastcompany.com/3046284/5-things-youll-learn-when-you-veer-off-a-traditional-career-path)

> #### veer (v.) [on Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=veer)
>
> 1580s, "to change direction" (originally of the wind; 1610s of a ship),
> from French *virer* "to turn" (12c.), of uncertain origin,
> perhaps (Diez) from the Latin stem *vir-* in *viriae* (plural) "bracelets." Gamillscheg finds von Wartburg's derivation of it from a Vulgar Latin contraction of Latin *vibrare* "to shake" to be *nicht möglich*.

> #### Etymology [on Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/virer)
>
> From [Vulgar Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgar_Latin) *[*virō](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Latin/viro&action=edit&redlink=1)*, probably from [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[vibrō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vibro#Latin)* (in which case it is a [doublet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#doublet) of *[vibrer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vibrer#French)*) or possibly from an alteration of *[gȳrō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gyro#Latin)*. Compare [Italian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_language) *[virare](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/virare#Italian)*, [Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_language) *[virar](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/virar#Spanish)*. Or, possibly from [Gaulish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaulish) *[*viru](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Reconstruction:Gaulish/viru&action=edit&redlink=1)* (“to deviate, veer off”), itself derived from *[viros](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viros#Gaulish)* (“round, crooked”).

Comment: In a nautical context, the word *virer* is perfectly polite. The words “Virez à tribord !”  mean “Turn to starboard !”. But it is definitely **not** polite in an (end of) employment context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Virer*** means to cease to employ, to dismiss someone. I wasn't aware of the verb "to unemploy", especially with that meaning.

Anyway, there are several other ways to say it in French like *licencier, renvoyer, mettre à la porte, foutre dehors, congédier, limoger, slacker (Québec), remercier...* just like in English *to fire, dismiss, terminate, lay off, sack, make redundant, throw out, show the door, can, pink slip, downsize...*

In the case of ***virer***, the meaning is straigthforward: to quickly change the direction of someone's career.

Comment: Thanks. **You know that** I know there are "there are several other ways to say it in French like *licencier, renvoyer*". Because you answered my other question on *renvoyer*!

Comment: Yes, I know it now but I didn't when I wrote this reply.

Comment: *Limoger* is the one with the most interesting etymology.

Comment: I don’t think ‘change the direction of someone’s career’ is how _virer_ came to mean ‘fire’. It seems more likely that it comes from ‘turn’ > ‘turn away’ > ‘send away’ > ‘fire’. [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/virer) illustrates this development in the senses under II A: [1] _tourner retourner_ (arch.); [2] _déplacer d'un mouvement tournant_; [4] **a** _changer quelque chose de place, lancer avec brusquerie_, **b** _faire sortir quelqu'un d'un lieu violemment; mettre à la porte, en partic. renvoyer quelqu'un de la situation qu'il occupe, congédier_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes. I made a shortcut between the direction the employee is sent to and the new direction of their career. In both cases, it's indeed a turn.

Answer (score 0):

"Virer" means "to turn".  Think of "I turn you back"

Comment: Bienvenue sur French language SE.  Can you include more information about how this addresses the question?  Please do take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help].